# Production method of custom seed mir451? How to edit middle of a fragment?

Tags: genetics, plasmids, synthetic-biology

I am trying to create a plasmid that produces mir451 targeting a new gene, so I need to alter the seed sequence. The seed sequence is 7 bp long, so I think that is too long for PCR mutagenesis. How do people generally alter sequences that would be in the middle of an amplicon? Buying it from gBlock or something is an option, but if I need to try multiple permutations that could get really expensive quickly. I haven't done any synthetic biology in a long time so sorry if this a basic question or it doesn't make sense. Thanks [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think 7nt is ok for site-directed mutagenesis, see older question [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/105512/how-many-non-pairing-bases-can-a-pcr-primer-have-in-directed-mutagenesis/105513#105513).

The size constraint comes largely from being able to have enough flanking homology 5' and 3' of the substitution on your primer (e.g. Figure 1 [here](https://www.idtdna.com/pages/education/decoded/article/site-directed-mutagenesis-improvements-to-established-methods)). [This provider](https://www.neb.com/applications/cloning-and-synthetic-biology/site-directed-mutagenesis) suggests >=10nt of 3' homology, [this other provider](https://blog.addgene.org/site-directed-mutagenesis-by-pcr) suggests at least 11nt on either side.

gBlock is almost certainly the fastest and removes the experimental error side, but if you need to screen a lot of combinations SDM seems workable.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful, I'll probably go with gblock first then maybe try SDM to test sequences if its cheaper